# html in webform bigger compared to html in internet explorer

Tags: html, c++, forms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

[image]

I uploaded the problem. It's quite visual.
The same html looks very bad on a webbrowser inside a c++ form.

Comment: What is the question here?  What would an answer that you are expecting look like?

Comment: @ScottHunter how to fix it?

Comment: Fix the code that you haven't shared?  What web browser?  What is a C++ form?

Comment: @ScottHunter: The question is tagged [webbrowser-control] and that tag has a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check (using Fiddler or similar tools) is whether the same HTML is used. You might be missing a .css file or so.

The next suspect would be the HTTP headers. You might be trying to set the HTML directly in the webbrowser control instead of using HTTP to fetch it, but in that case you miss the HTTP headers.